# Xcode Help using if statement to hide buttons

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, if-statement

I've got 3 buttons - when button one 'grassleft' is pressed I want to hide it/make it fade out (and push to a next segue), but only after the buttons two and three have been pressed and have disappeared first. I don't want grassleft method to push segue until grassmiddle and grassright have disappeared. Don't think i'm using the if statement properly. My code:

```
- (IBAction)grassleft:(id)sender {



if ((grassrightbutton.hidden == YES)) {

    grassleftbutton.alpha = 0;

}
if ((grassmiddlebutton.hidden == YES)) {

    grassleftbutton.alpha = 0;

}

else {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{

                         self.grassleftbutton.alpha = 0;



                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         self.grassleftbutton.alpha = 0.0;
                         [grassleftshakes invalidate];

                     }];

}


    double delayInSeconds = 1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotoyakenclosure" sender:self];
    });


}





- (IBAction)grassmiddle:(id)sender {



[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{

                     self.grassmiddlebutton.alpha = 0;



                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     self.grassmiddlebutton.alpha = 0.0;
                     [grassmiddleshakes invalidate];
                     grassmiddlebutton.hidden = YES;


                 }];


}



- (IBAction)grassright:(id)sender {

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{

                     self.grassrightbutton.alpha = 0;



 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

     self.grassrightbutton.alpha = 0.0;
         [grassrightshakes invalidate];
     grassrightbutton.hidden = YES;


 }];


}
```

Comment: Post the code that you have so far

Comment: correct me if i am wrong. u have 3 buttons. after pressing button1, it has to be disappeared, and after pressing button2 it also has to be disappeared and after pressing button3 and push to next segue

Comment: Have posted code. I want the first button 'grassleft' to disappear and push one pressed, but only if the other two buttons have been pressed first (are hidden/alphas are 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take two int variable like middleFlag and RightFlag

Now in grassRightButton's Action method assign rightFlag = 1 and hide the grassRightButton

and in grassMiddleButton's Action Method assign middleFlag = 1 and hide the grassMiddleButton

Now, in grassLeft method

```
- (IBAction)grassleft:(id)sender {

    if (rightFlag == 1 && middleFlag == 1 ) {

        grassleftbutton.alpha = 0;

        // if you want that segue only performed if the 2 and 3 button are pressed then put your code here for perform segue.

    }
    else {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.grassleftbutton.alpha = 0;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         button.alpha = 0.0;
                         [grassleftshakes invalidate];
                         double delayInSeconds = 1;
                         dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
                         dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                             [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotoyakenclosure" sender:self];
                         });
                     }];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion` method on `UIView` and modify the `alpha` of the buttons.

But if you want more help than that, you'll have to show us your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're current code says: If button1 is pressed, hide it and perform the segue. If button two is pressed, hide it and perform the segue. If button two is hidden, perform the segue.

So your code will perform the segue regardless of button1's state. To change that, you need to use `else if`.

Also, your perform segue code is executed whenever button three is pressed, you should instead add it to the `UIView` animation's completion block.

```
- (IBAction)grassleft:(id)sender {

    if ((grassrightbutton.hidden == YES)) {

        grassleftbutton.alpha = 0;

    }
    else if ((grassmiddlebutton.hidden == YES)) {

        grassleftbutton.alpha = 0;
    }

    else {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             self.grassleftbutton.alpha = 0;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             button.alpha = 0.0;
                             [grassleftshakes invalidate];
                             double delayInSeconds = 1;
                             dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
                             dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                                 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotoyakenclosure" sender:self];
                             });
                         }];

    }
}
```